# Grid Column Touch Determination Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to determine which of 6 columns of the screen a user touched. The available information is which cell of an on-screen grid the user touched. The screen's grid looks like:

```
     Top Bezel
|1  2  3  4  5  6 |
|7  8  9  10 11 12|
|13 14 15 16 17 18|
|19 20 21 22 23 24|
|25 26 27 28 29 30|  
|31 31 32 33 34 35|
|36 37 38 39 40 41|
...etc. (21 rows total)
```

If a user touches cell #10, for example, I want to find an algorithm I can implement in Java to determine that the touch occurred on column 3. If a user touched cell #13, I want to determine that they touched column 0.

How can I implement this efficiently in a Java method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int column(int cell) { return (cell - 1) % 6; }
```